# Как циклически сдвинуть значения ключей в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Изначально у нас есть такой словарь:

`rooms = {'room_1': False, 'room_2': True, 'room_3': None}`

Как циклически переместить значения ключей вправо/влево, чтобы вышло так:

`rooms = {'room_1': None, 'room_2': False, 'room_3': True}`

или так:

`rooms = {'room_1': True, 'room_2': None, 'room_3': False}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант:

1. Получаем **значения** ключей словаря в виде списка, при помощи функции `.values()`
2. Перемещаем элементы полученного списка, при помощи конструкции со срезами, реализующей циклический сдвиг
3. Группируем старые ключи с новыми сдвинутыми значениями, функцией `zip()`
4. Создаем итоговый словарь, используя конструктор `dict()`

---

Код:

```
rooms = {'room_1': False, 'room_2': True, 'room_3': None}

def shift_dict_values(dct, shift):
    values = list(dct.values())
    return dict(zip(dct.keys(), values[-shift:] + values[:-shift]))

print(shift_dict_values(rooms, 1))
print(shift_dict_values(rooms, 2))
```

Вывод:

```
{'room_1': None, 'room_2': False, 'room_3': True}
{'room_1': True, 'room_2': None, 'room_3': False}
```