# Как сделать сдвиг значений ключа словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть изначальный словарь:

```
rooms = {'room_1': 1, 'room_2': 2, 'room_3': 3, 'room_4': 4}
```

Нужно сделать функцию для сдвига значений ключей вправо и влево на определенное кол-во шагов, которое мы задаем в вводе.
Что я имею ввиду:

Если мы вводим что step = 1, то выполняется следующий сдвиг:

```
rooms = {'room_1': 4, 'room_2': 1, 'room_3': 2, 'room_4': 3}
```

Если мы вводим что step = -1, то выполняется следующий сдвиг:

```
rooms = {'room_1': 2, 'room_2': 3, 'room_3':4, 'room_4': 1}
```

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема?

Comment: напишите функцию, которая будет принимать на вход словарь и количество шагов для сдвига и возвращать измененный словарь. в чем сложности? иногда нужно самому постараться решить задачу, чтобы хоть что-то отложилось

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Так то тут неоднократно такое спрашивали. Но вы лучше сами попытайтесь сделать, иначе ничему не научитесь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как циклически сдвинуть значения ключей в словаре?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовый код для сдвига значений словаря:

```
def shift_dict(d, shift):
    keys = list(d.keys())
    values = list(d.values())
    n = len(d)
    new_values = values[-shift % n:] + values[:-shift % n]
    return dict(zip(keys, new_values))


d = {'room_1': 1, 'room_2': 2, 'room_3': 3, 'room_4': 4}
shift = 1
print(shift_dict(d, shift)) 
 
# {'room_1': 4, 'room_2': 1, 'room_3': 2, 'room_4': 3}
```